# MPC in gekko - add dynamics in process

Tags: python, gekko, mpc

I'm working on an MPC using gekko and I have face a problem to add dynamics to process. I have equations to two control properties thus once the program is running I need to add dynamic on MV, one by one. This is a non-linear process. In the future I will use a equation to calculate the gain. The following is the original code.

[image: Graphic result]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import math 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
#m.open_folder()
t= np.linspace(0,500,100)
m.time=t

m.options.CV_TYPE = 2 # squared error
m.options.IMODE = 6  #MPC
m.options.SOLVER = 2

# Parameters
Tm = np.ones(len(t))*260
Tm[60:] = 265

Tr = m.Param(value=Tm)
Ti=m.Param(value=30)
HT=m.Param(value=230)

# Manipulated variable
F = m.Param(value=0.11, lb=0, ub=0.65)

j = m.MV(value=1, lb=0, ub=40)
j.STATUS = 1  
j.DCOST = 0.1 
j.DMAX = 5   

mv1 = m.MV(value=20, lb=18, ub=22)
mv1.STATUS = 1  
mv1.DCOST = 0.1 
mv1.DMAX = 0.1  
To = 8.6576*mv1 + 112.66

#MI
sp_m = np.ones(len(t))*4
sp_m[30:] = 10
sp_m[50:]=20
O_sp = m.Param(value=sp_m)

# Controlled Variable
P2 = m.Var(value=10) 

m.Obj((O_sp-O2)**2)

P1 = m.CV(value=94)
P1.STATUS = 1 
P1.SP = 95    
P1.TR_INIT = 1 
P1.TAU = 30   
P1.FDELAY=2  
P1.WSP=1   

# Process model
m.Equation(P1==(((To-(Ti+4))/(((16.15-0.019*(To+Ti)/2))*mv1))-0.06*F)*100)
m.Equation(P2==m.exp(0.792*m.log(j)-3.09*m.log(HT)+13.87*m.log(Tr)+3.06*m.log(1+F)-59.9))

m.options.IMODE = 6 # MPC
m.solve(disp=False)

import json
with open(m.path+'//results.json') as f:
    results = json.load(f)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,15))

plt.subplot(5,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,mv1,'b-',label='MV Optimized')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.ylabel('MV1')

plt.subplot(5,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,results['v2.tr'],'k-',label='Setpoint')
plt.plot(m.time,P1,'r--',label='CV Response')
plt.ylim([93, 96])
plt.ylabel('Conversion(%)')
plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.subplot(5,1,3)
plt.plot(m.time,results['p6'],'b-',label='MV Optimized')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.ylabel('MV2')

plt.subplot(5,1,4)
plt.plot(m.time,results['p8'],'k-',label='Setpoint')
plt.plot(m.time,results['v1'],'r--',label='CV Response')
plt.ylabel('P1(mu)')

plt.subplot(5,1,5)
plt.plot(m.time,Tm,'k-',label='Reactor temp(°C)')
plt.ylabel('T (°C)')
plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

For example I need to change the MV in equation

```py
P2==m.exp(0.792*m.log(j)-3.09*m.log(HT)+13.87 \ 
          *m.log(Tr)+3.06*m.log(1+F)-59.9))
```

I have been tried:

Option 1: Doesn't work

```py
U1 =0.11/(1.8*(s**2)+2.88*s+1)*m.exp(-s) #transfer function
u1 = inverse_laplace_transform(U1,s,t)
P2==m.exp(0.792*m.log(j***u1**)-3.09*m.log(HT)\
          +13.87*m.log(Tr)+3.06*m.log(1+F)-59.9))
```

Option 2: Doesn't work

```py
m.Equation(ft==k*(1-m.exp(-(t-tau_d)/tau))
m.Equation(P2==m.exp(0.792*m.log(j***ft**)-3.09*m.log(HT)\
            +13.87*m.log(Tr)+3.06*m.log(1+F)-59.9)))
```

```
Result: Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)
(((-(10.1010101010101-p1)))/(p2))
(((-(15.15151515151515-p1)))/(p2))
STOPPING...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to add dynamics in Gekko including [ARX (Time Series)](https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/ARXTimeSeries), [Differential equations](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html#dt), [state space](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/LinearStateSpace), [discrete state space](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/DiscreteStateSpace), and others. The dynamic equation for the MV isn't clear from the question. In the first option, there is a second order system with a one time unit delay:

```py
U1 =0.11/(1.8*(s**2)+2.88*s+1)*m.exp(-s) #transfer function
u1 = inverse_laplace_transform(U1,s,t)
```

Here is material to help with getting the [second order system into a differential equation form](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SecondOrderSystems). For the time delay, use a discrete state space model or ARX model that is an additional model element.

The second option that didn't work appears to be an explicit solution to a dynamic step response:

```py
m.Equation(ft==k*(1-m.exp(-(t-tau_d)/tau))
```

Instead of the step response, use the original differential equation as show in the [first order systems material](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/FirstOrderSystems).

The original code that you posted does not produce the chart. There are several missing variable declarations. For future posts, include a minimal and complete working example of the problem for more specific feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your help teacher. In fact I need do use time like MV.

Comment: Time can be an adjustable parameter that is optimized with the solver. Here is an example: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MinimizeFinalTime